# How to highlight PHP, HTML & JavaScript at same time with Notepad++?

Tags: php, notepad++, html, javascript, syntax-highlighting

The file extension and language is PHP, and need to highlight HTML and JavaScript at the same time with the main language PHP in Notepad++

Example of code to highlight:

```
<?php
    $form_name = 'index';
?>

<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script>alert('One = ' + 1);</script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" value="<?php $form_name; ?>">
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ 6.7.9.2 from PortableApps I have here does that out of the box. File is named "file.php"

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIiUa.png)